# Validate phone format on submit form

Tags: javascript

I want to validate the value of phone number input to match this format
(555)5555-555

I'm using this script but It's not doning anything on click on the img

```
function submit() {
            var phone = $('#number').val();
            if(!phone.match(/^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$/) || phone == "") {
                $("#phoneNumberInvalid").show();
                return false;
            } else {
                document.forms["phoneForm"].submit();
                return true;
            }
        }
```

the form:

```
        <form name="phoneForm"  method="POST" onsubmit="return submit();">

<div class="continueDiv">
    <img id="continu" src="web/static/media/images/continue.jpg"
        onclick="submit();" />
</div>
    <div id="phoneNumberInvalid"
            style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 50px; z-index:1; display:none;"
            class="invalid">Enter a valid phone number.</div>
<div id="phoneNumberDiv"
            style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 220px; width: 550px; height: 112px; z-index: 4; vertical-align: middle;">
            <img src="web/static/media/images/phoneLogo.gif">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="number" name="number" type="text" class="phoneNumClass" />
        </div>

</form>
```

The form not validate the form using the Js code
Any advise ?

Comment: Just noticed that, If I hit F12 to debug , the code works and validate the form with display the error message?! It doesn't make any sense. Still looking why that.

Comment: clear your browser cache run again

Comment: I did clean all the cash, but no luck.

Comment: check with all browser you have

Comment: I've seen this happen before where in debug mode the code runs correctly. Try renaming your function to something besides submit and see if that helps at all. Submit might have special meaning when it's in the context of a form.

Comment: It worked on Firefox fine, no IE ot chrome,

Comment: Changing the function name fixed it for all browsers! That's weird.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the function  name fixed it for all browsers! thanks Observer!

```
function validate() {
                var phone = $('#number').val();
                if(!phone.match(/^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$/) || phone == "") {
                    $("#phoneNumberInvalid").show();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    document.forms["phoneForm"].submit();
                    return true;
                }
            }
```